# Is there any way I can modify SVG code in a function with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg

So i have to create about 1000 svgs; however, all of them have the same code but different text on it. Is there a way I can display an svg in a for loop, then modify the code the change the text in the svg code?
For example,

```
for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
 /*display this -->*/ MarkerIcon.svgAsset(assetName: 'assets/svg/${svgName.toString()}.svg'
//Code to change svg name so that it will modify that one svg file and print it 
//with the a different text on the next iteration
  
}
```

Comment: You could edit the raw svg string in a loop.

Comment: Looking at `package:marker_icon`'s API documentation, it does not seem to provide a direct way to load SVG data from memory.  You would need to: A. Write the modified SVG to disk first. B. Make a `Widget` that renders the SVG and use [`widgetToIcon`](https://pub.dev/documentation/marker_icon/latest/marker_icon/MarkerIcon/widgetToIcon.html) instead. C. Modify the [`svgAsset`](https://pub.dev/documentation/marker_icon/latest/marker_icon/MarkerIcon/svgAsset.html) code to allow to use an SVG string you provide.

Comment: DrawableRoot svgRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(rawSvg, rawSvg); would seem to work with https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Comment: when I edit the raw string, will it keep the previous marker which I placed the same or change that too?

Comment: @jamesdlin, What field can I use to modify the svgAsset code via that method. I am currently doing var icon = await MarkerIcon.svgAsset(AssetName:.....); How can I modify the actual text in the svg with this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "what field".  You would need to modify the string passed to `svg.fromSvgString`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, will passing the whole svg file into a MarkerIcon.svg work? like this: 

 var icon = await MarkerIcon.svgAsset(
  assetName: <svg>...</svg>,
context: context,
size:30,):
Then I can just modify that svg code and it should work?

Comment: No, `MarkerIcon.svgAsset` expects its argument to be an asset name.  I'm saying that you would need to modify that code (or copy/refactor it into a new function) that allows a caller to pass its own raw SVG string.

Comment: @jamesdlin Okay thank you. I'll try and figure out how to make a function to modify the text in the SVG. thank you for the help